# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 3948 (42000): Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am working on a python project with MySQL connectivity. I have MySQL as a shell, i.e.,I need to use `mysqlsh`  command in the Terminal to use MySQL(I am using MacOS Mojave 10.14.6). I needed to use a csv file to store data taken from user and then transfer it to a MySQL database. After doing some research, I found the best way to do it was by giving the`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command to `my_c.execute()`('*my_c*' is the cursor I defined to use for Python-MySQL connectivity) in Python. However when I run the command: `my_c.execute('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"/test1\Desktop/Python/Practice/body.csv\" INTO TABLE POQ COLUMNS TERMINATED BY \",\" ESCAPED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'IGNORE 1 LINES')`

I get the following errors:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 3948 (42000): Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

Here is a screenshot of the code:

[image]
#Password Removed here.

As both the files(python and the source file) are in the same directory, I tried removing the full path of the file, and just writing the file name; but that didn't work either.

Here is the screenshot of the error output:

[image]

I tried researching the errors, and many suggested to use the command `show global variables like 'local_infile';` and `set global local_infile=true;` in MySQL. Sure the value changed from NULL to ON. But there was still no difference.

[image]

#Some solutions suggested to make changes to the *'my.cnf'* file or the *'my.ini'*. But when I tried to find it, I found that it doesn't exist.
#Some suggested to make changes to secure-file-priv in the file: file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf. But this file was also not found.

Can someone pls tell what is wrong and how to fix it? Pls give step-by-step solution as I am not very good with the in-depth technical details of it.

Other information:

1. OS: MacOS Mojave(10.14.6)
2. Python version: 3.9.2
3. MySQL shell version: 8.0.23

If you need other information, do tell.

I tried researching the errors, and many suggested to use the command `show global variables like 'local_infile';` and `set global local_infile=true;` in MySQL. Sure the value changed from NULL to ON. But there was still no difference.

#Some solutions suggested to make changes to the *'my.cnf'* file or the *'my.ini'*. But when I tried to find it, I found that it doesn't exist.
#Some suggested to make changes to secure-file-priv in the file: file /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf. But this file was also not found.

Answer (score 1):

Add the statement:

`allow_local_infile` when defining the connectivity.

Finally it will look like:

`mydb = mysql.connect(user='root', host='localhost', passwd='', allow_local_infile=True)'

This fixed it for me.(of course it is assuming that the local_infile variable it set to True in MySQL too)